# Is this code from Java Concurrency in practice ThreadSafe?

Tags: java, concurrency

It might seem silly but I am unable to get this one. VolatileCachedFactorizer is keeping an instance of OneValueCache and re-initialising it in every call. Shouldn't this assignment be done in a synchronized block?

```
    @Immutable
    class OneValueCache {
        private final BigInteger   lastNumber;
        private final BigInteger[] lastFactors;

        public OneValueCache(BigInteger i, BigInteger[] factors) {
            lastNumber = i;
            lastFactors = Arrays.copyOf(factors, factors.length);
        }

        public BigInteger[] getFactors(BigInteger i) {
            if (lastNumber == null || !lastNumber.equals(i))
                return null;
            else
                return Arrays.copyOf(lastFactors, lastFactors.length);
        }
    }

    public class VolatileCachedFactorizer implements Servlet {
        private volatile OneValueCache cache =
            new OneValueCache(null, null);
        public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) {
            BigInteger i = extractFromRequest(req);
            BigInteger[] factors = cache.getFactors(i);
            if (factors == null) {
                factors = factor(i);
                cache = new OneValueCache(i, factors); // is this line ok?
            }
            encodeIntoResponse(resp, factors);
        }
    }
```

Comment: more like code review post.

Comment: This is not for code review, this code is from Java Concurrency in practice. I am somehow confused on this.

Comment: Why do you think it should be in a `synchronized` block? What would it synchronize on?

Comment: Because the construction of the `OneValueCache` object is not atomic. It can `synchronize` on `this` object.

Comment: volatile makes it threadsafe, you don't need to synchronize.

Comment: @SunnyAgarwal Code in the constructor _happens-before_ any code that runs after the constructor exits. So in general, there is no need to ever `synchronize` on `this` inside the constructor, assuming you're not passing `this` off to some other code during the construction.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I was talking about putting this line `cache = new OneValueCache(i, factors); ` in `synchronised` block?

Comment: Note that writes to final variables in a constructor are visible after construction.

Comment: @SunnyAgarwal Yes, that line is okay without having to use a `synchronized` block, because `volatile` fields have _happens-before_ for reads and writes. So a thread may get an _older_ value if the timing is wrong, but never an inconsistent value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cache` variable is `volatile`. This means that a write action to it *happens-before* a subsequent read action which observes the written value. Therefore the object in question has been *safely published* to the other thread and no further synchronization is necessary.

Note that, since `OneValueCache` is an immutable class, even without the volatile ("publishing via a data race") the code would *still* be thread-safe in the sense that a thread, if it ever observes an object, it will be guaranteed to observe it fully initialized. Without the `volatile`, though, there is no guarantee that the object's reference will ever be observed by another thread.

Comment: Since the construction of `OneValueCache` is not atomic, can't there be a case where two threads are simultaneously constructing its object and which one gets assigned to `cache` reference is unpredictable?

Comment: @SunnyAgarwal Of course not. Each thread is constructing a _new_ instance of the cache. And there are no static variables or other shared state between those two threads.

Comment: @SunnyAgarwal You mean the *order* in which it gets assigned is unpredictable, since both assignments will definitely occur. But the order is not important because, if both threads are caching for the same value of `i`, the instances they assign will be exactly the same.

Comment: @WilliamF.Jameson I think Sunny means that cache = new OneValueCache(i, factors); is not atomic, which can be reordering. So is it possible that another thread will see a partially constructed OneValueCache?